# Why my post is marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I published this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763279/no-symbol-found-for-website-in-visual-studio-2013) but it is marked as duplicate. Occording to me it's wrong, I explained why in comment but moderators don't answer me. Moreover, the link proposed does not solve my issue

Can you explain me why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First to clear up a couple of misconceptions

1. 99% of the time, questions are closed and/or reopened by the community, not the moderators.  Users with the appropriate privileges (which are defined by their reputation) can vote to close and vote to reopen questions.
2. There are not roving bands of moderators who roam around looking for comments to handle specific issues.  If you need to specifically communicate an issue to a site moderator, you should flag the post, but as I mentioned above, closing and reopening is generally a community function, so moderators are generally unlikely to override the community's decision unless a clear mistake was made.
3. The biggest cause of mistaken duplicates is clarity.  The community certainly makes mistakes, but if 5 users made the same mistake, they could be misunderstanding your question.

The proper way to try to get a question reopened is:

1. Commenting is often not nearly enough to reopen a question.  You need to make your explanation more visible.  Comments are buried in with other comments and are often not easily noticeable.
2. Instead, you should edit your questions as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not).  Take note of all of the answers as all have some good information.
3. And please do not just put "*EDIT: this is not'a duplicate because....*".  Take the time to incorporate the differences between your question and the proposed duplicate into your question.
4. When you edit your question, it should be placed into a review queue in which users with privileges to reopen questions will be able to evaluate

For your specific issue, I don't think the reason you provided is necessary enough to make it not a duplicate.  The fact you are building a web page and not a desktop app is probably not enough to make the solution different.  While that may instead be relavant, it by itself isn't a reason to reopen the question

When trying to edit your question, don't worry too much about the details of the duplicate question.  Instead focus on why **the answers** do not solve your problem.  Why don't those solutions help?  Did you try them?  What were the results?

Comment: For me it's not the same constraint on WebSite app and Desktop app, and the different is enought to understand the not duplicate post

Answer (score 4):

It was marked as a duplicate by a jury of your peers because the way it was stated it appeared to be a duplicate. Note that you can ask the same question many different ways but the answer can be the same, and most of the time these "different ways" will still be considered a duplicate. This doesn't mean your question was bad, it simply means that there is no need to answer your question separately - you can simply be pointed to the previous question/answer.

But even though you found the cause, the selected duplicate is still fundamentally right  - your source file didn't match what was actually being executed. You should add your answer to the linked original if it isn't already there (don't just leave it as a comment on your own question).

Comment: Ok I put my answer to the post original